# looping until key release or until key press

Tags: lua, roblox

im looking to make a lag switch for a game and im wondering if instead of having to wait 7 seconds how would i be able to make it so the effect is on for as long as im holding down right control if this isnt possible perhaps it could be press until i press it again? i made this from a tutorial so dont have much to any lua knowledge, any help much appreciated

code:

```
setting = settings().Network
local Effect = Instance.new("ColorCorrectionEffect")
Effect.Parent = game.Lighting
Effect.Saturation = -1
Effect.Brightness = 0
Effect.Contrast = 0
Effect.Enabled = false
function onKeyPress(inputObject, gameProcessedEvent)
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.RightControl then
        Effect.Enabled = true
        setting.IncomingReplicationLag = 1000
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed * 3
        wait(7)
        Effect.Enabled = false
        setting.IncomingReplicationLag = 0
    end
end
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:connect(onKeyPress)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using the [InputBegan](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/UserInputService/InputBegan) signal, you can listen for the [InputEnded](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/UserInputService/InputEnded) signal to know when to stop.

```
function onKeyDown(inputObject, gameProcessedEvent)
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.RightControl then
        Effect.Enabled = true
        -- ... do other things here
    end
end
function onKeyUp(inputObject, gameProccessedEvent)
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.RightControl then
        Effect.Enabled = false
        -- ... do other things here
    end
end

local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(onKeyDown)
UIS.InputEnded:Connect(onKeyUp)
```